# How to show this $H^1$ space is separable?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $H = \{u \in L^2(0,T) : u' \in L^2(0,T), u(T) = u(0)\}$ be the space of $H^1$ functions $u$ with $u(T) = u(0)$. How to show that this space is separable with the usual $H^1$ norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a subspace of a separable space.